# Capture Bluetooth communication in Java

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I have a small device that works with bluetooth and I want to capture command launched from this device to use them on my computer, anyway 
I tried to use BlueCove Library

But all I receive are some chars, and when I try to launch commands from the device, `InputStream` doesn't receive anything

```
public void run() {
    try {
        // prepare to receive data
        DataInputStream inputStream   = new DataInputStream(mConnection.openInputStream());
        System.out.println("waiting for input");

        while (true) {
            int command = inputStream.read(new byte[8]);
            //int donnee = inputStream.read() ; 
            if (command == EXIT_CMD) {
              System.out.println("finish process");
                break;
            }
            processCommand(command);



        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to show `mConnection ` settings or Configuratios

Comment: Just formatting, the question is good